# OnClick event not working in google chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have used the onclick() javascript event in my cake app. but that not work in google chrome and safari.
here is the my code

```
<select name="ovwear" >
            <option>--Select Category--</option>
            <?php
            $i = 1; 

            foreach($styleDetail as $key=>$val) { ?>


            <option onClick="catDetail(<?php echo $val['shop_style_categories']['cat_id'].",".$val['shop_style_categories']['parent_id'] ?>);" value="<?php echo $i;?>">Category <?php echo $i;?></option>

            <?php $i++; } ?>

            </select>
```

here is the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function catDetail(cat_id,parent_id){
        //alert("called here");
        var cat_id = cat_id;
        var parent_id = parent_id;
            jQuery.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "/admin/shop/styledata",
                          data:"cat_id=" + cat_id,
                          dataType: "html",
                          success: function(data) {
                            $("#alertt").html(data);
                         } 
            });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: why are you not using $.post()

Answer (score 3):

```
onclick has to be on `<select` instead of `<option`

<select name="ovwear"  onClick=.....
```

Comment: So i am use only <option> tag inside the froeach loop not select tag

Comment: I understand. you need to change your approach. Define onchange on select and pass you required value, which has been set in the loop

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't attach an `onclick` on `<option>`. Better use `onchange` on `<select>` instead.

And since you are using jQuery, take advantage of using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach handlers. Also, use `data-*` attributes for custom data on tags. More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4564711/575527).

Answer (score 0):

You should put onclick event on the select element and not on the options.

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery, therefore, you should *use* jQuery. You should be binding to the change event of the select element itself, and storing these relevant values as data attributes:

```
<?php
    $o =  "";
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $styleDetail ); $i++ ) {
        $o .= sprintf("<option data-cat-id='%s' data-parent-id='%s'>%s</option>",
                       $styleDetail[$i]['shop_style_categories']['cat_id'],
                       $styleDetail[$i]['shop_style_categories']['parent_id'],
                       "Category " . $i+1 );
    }
?>
<select name="ovwear"><?php echo $o; ?></select>
```

Next, we need to bind the data up:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("select[name='ovwear']").on("change", function(){
            var selected = $("option:selected", this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/admin/shop/styledata",
                data: { 'cat_id':$(selected).data("cat-id") },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#alert").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thansk for your awesome reply, but this show only 1,1,1,... in dropdown
<select name="ovwear"><?php echo $o; ?></select>

Comment: @user1436533 If this solved your problem, please consider accepting as by clicking the check-mark next to the answer.