# Attach data to HTML nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This question has been asked before, but most of the answers revolve around HTML5.

My DOCTYPE is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

I need to attach data (phone dialling code) to option values of a select:

```
<select id="id_creditCardCountry">  
<option value="ax">Aland Islands - AX</option> 
<option value="al">Albania - AL</option> 
<option value="dz">Algeria - DZ</option><!--e.g. Attach dial code "(+213)" -->
<option value="as">American Samoa - AS</option>
<option value="ad">Andorra - AD</option>
<option value="ai">Anguilla - AI</option>
etc
```

There seem to be numerous ways to accomplish this. I need to find the best one (by best I mean most cross browser and efficient).

- The jQuery "data" function http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data -- if this is the best method, can anyone give guidance of how to use in this instance?
- Set data based on element ID - This involves having to give an id to every option in the select.
- Further suggestions?

Comment: may be this can help you out <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564659/adding-additional-data-to-select-options-using-jquery>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
$("#id_creditCardCountry option[value='ax']").data("dial-code", "+213");
```

If you have a JS array of all the countries and dial codes then you could loop through them all:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= countryArray.length; i++){
    $("#id_creditCardCountry option[value='"+countryArray[i]+"']").data("dial-code", ""+dialCodeArray[i]+"");
}
```

However, this may be something to consider doing server side if you're already outputting a list of countries. For example:

```
<option value="ax" data-dial="+213">Aland Islands - AX</option>
```