# How to retrive the value before colon in below program

Tags: javascript

This is my select tag in HTML 
I am retriving the value as shown below

Could anybody please tell me how can retrieve the value before Colon (:)
for instance if it is 200:Java programming language I need only 200 as value

```
<select name = "book" id="selSeaShells">
  <option></option>
  <option value = "100:C programming language">C programming language</option>
  <option value = "200:Java programming language">Java programming language</option>
</select>

function myFunction() {
    var quantityvalue = document.getElementById("quan").value;
    var selObj = document.getElementById('selSeaShells');
    var optionselectedvalue;
    var optionselectedtext;

    for (i = 0; i < selObj.options.length; i++) {
        if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
            optionselectedvalue = selObj.options[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example does not have a DOM element with id 'quan'.

Comment: Perhaps you may like to use [data-attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564659/adding-additional-data-to-select-options-using-jquery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you can do

```
optionselectedvalue.split(':')[0]
```

A [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/CBGVb/)

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the value from it using either jquery or regular javascript commands.

Then with the value use the `split` function use this code on the String value `.split(":")` it returns an array you will want the first index so the total code to put on the string is `.split(":")[0]`.

If you want it as a number use the `parseInt` or `parseFloat` function on the result.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Karthikr.
That is a good answer
I want to add that you can get rid of that for loop and increase the performance of your code by using selectedIndex.

`var optionselectedvalue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;`

Here is a [jsbin demonstrating it](http://jsbin.com/afolat/1/edit) (Karthikr's answer is also in the bin)