# Javascript Select Value Load

Tags: javascript, html

I made a table with a dropdown menu.

```
<tr>
    <td>items</td>
    <td><select id="afewitems">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">item1</option>
        <option value="2">item2</option>
    </td></select>
</tr>
```

With javascript (not jQuery) i want to dynamicly load items on the screen based on the selection.
Example: when i select item1 (value="1") i want extra information loaded on the webpage based on the selection. (text and/or images)

I found this on the site:
[Adding additional data to select options using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564659/adding-additional-data-to-select-options-using-jquery)
http://jsfiddle.net/GsdCj/2/

So my question is: 
How can i load pre-written information in Java based on Select ID/Value?

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the `onchange` HTML `<select>` attribute.

```
<select id="afewitems" onchange="changeInfo(this)">
<!--  (option tags) -->
<div id="info"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function changeInfo(el) {
    var info = [ 
        "some text",       // option 0
        "something else",  // option 1
        "..."              // option 2
    ];
    var val = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = info[val];
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnvHU/)**

Here's a modification for multiple `<select>` tags.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUpnu/1/)

Comment: Hey Der Flatulator, 

Thank you for the quick response.

What i understood so far is :
You made a function with 2 variables, Info and Val.
The info variable contains the custom text based on the values?
The val variable im not so sure what it does but i think it gets the index you selected and print it as .innerHTML?

If you could explain what is happening in your code i would be one step closer to where i want to be :D.

Here you see i got more option tags
http://jsfiddle.net/dUpnu/
Thank you so much for helping out.

Comment: @user2950105 (Apologies for the late response.) Of course, you are correct in that `info` is an array of text (or HTML) for each option tag. `val` is simply the `value` attribute of the currently selected option tag, so with your option tag: `<option value="1">item1</option>`, `val` will be equal to `1`. The value is used to index into the array.