# hide particular value in the option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following AJAX call and right now I have the `description`, `name` and `id` of the company in the dropdown menu.

I am wondering if I can hide something like  `data.company[i].id`. This will be hidden from the UI but I still want it because when a user selects a project, I am grabbing the id in my other logic.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'myurl',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.company, function(i) {
      $("#mylist").append('<option>' + data.company[i].description + ' | ' + data.company[i].name + ' | ' + data.company[i].id + '</option>');
    });
  },
  error: function(request, error) {
    $.growl.error({
      title: "Error",
      message: "Webservice request failed!"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: So do not display it..... use it as a value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding additional data to select options using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564659/adding-additional-data-to-select-options-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'myurl',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.company, function(i) {
        var optData = data.company[i].description;
        var optText = data.company[i].name;
        var optValue = data.company[i].id;
        $("#mylist").append(`<option data-description="${optData}" value="${optValue}">${optText}</option>`);
    });
  },
  error: function(request, error) {
    $.growl.error({
      title: "Error",
      message: "Webservice request failed!"
    });
  }
});
```

To get the currently selected value:

```
$('#mylist').val();
```

To get the currently selected text:

```
$('#mylist :selected').text();
```

To get the currently selected data:

```
$('#mylist :selected').data('description');
```

Comment: Thanks. Let's say if I want to hide `description` as well but want to retain it just like `id`. Is it possible to hide `description` and `id` and just display `name` as I am realizing the description is occupying too much real state?

Comment: Yes. Please check Rory's answer.. , you can set data.
data-description="${data.company[i].description}"
To retrieve description, use $('#mylist :selected').data('description')

Comment: Thanks but his answer is displaying description in the dropdown menu.Am I missing anything?

Comment: You need to remove data.company[i].description from optText. I have update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide a value from the UI but retain it so you can use it in your logic, try using a `data` attribute on the element. This is not visible to the users, but can be read back out when the option is selected.

Here's a basic example:

```js
let data = {
  company: [{
    description: 'Desc #1',
    name: 'Name #1',
    id: 'Id #1'
  },{
    description: 'Desc #2',
    name: 'Name #2',
    id: 'Id #2'
  },{
    description: 'Desc #3',
    name: 'Name #3',
    id: 'Id #3'
  }]  
}

let options = data.company.map(company => `<option data-id="${company.id}">${company.description} | ${company.name}</option>`);
$('#mylist').append(options).on('change', e => {
  let id = $(e.target).find('option:selected').data('id');
  console.log(e.target.value, id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mylist"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks. Let's say if I want to hide `description` as well but want to retain it just like `id`. Is it possible to hide `description` and `id` and just display `name` as I am realizing the description is occupying too much real state?

Comment: Sure, the same approach would work, just define another `data` attribute